# AWS Lex bot live human takeover

Tags: amazon-lex

I am building a bot on AWS Lex. I wanted to know if there is a way, I could integrate a live human take over when the bot is unable to handle some task or it needs to.

Tried searching but no luck.
If you could point me to some documentation or plugin, it would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using AWS SDK or deploying your bot on Facebook/Slack?

Comment: I am not using SDK yet. I deployed on Slack. Also used the WebApp. But not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Facility you are looking for then is not there in Lex yet. How did you use WhatsApp for bot?

Comment: I didnt use WhatsApp. I deployed a WebApp on a website.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, AWS Lex doesn't provide that functionality.

Source: I asked [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=804450#804450) question in the official AWS forums and an AWS member confirmed the information.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lex doesn't support live agent integration. Live agent feature is part of ticketing systems like Twilio Flex, Service cloud (salesforce), Service Now etc. Custom implementation has to be made for routing between live agent and the bot. More detailed inputs are in this blog: https://www.smartbots.ai/2019/06/12/how-to-implement-live-agent-feature-in-customer-support-chatbots/